# Adding preformatted buttons to a table with js (to condense white space)?

Tags: javascript, html

For a simple game I'm developing, I have a table of upgrades that is (originally) empty. Currently, the HTML is simple, just looks like this for the table:

```
<table id='upgradeTable'>
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

However, I have upgrades for this game. Each upgrade I have has a small HTML block that formats colors for different currencies, updates the costs of the upgrade and their effect, etc. An example of one follows:

```
<button id="mastersDegreeUpgButton" class="upgradeButtons" onClick="upgrade(UPGRADES[returnIndex(UPGRADES,'mastersDegreeUpg')])">Masters Degree </button>
<div class='tooltip' id='mastersDegreeUpgTooltip'>
    <span>Get your grad students into shape! And off a diet of ramen.
        <br /> </span>
    <span class='tooltipMoneyColor'>
        <span class='boldedNumbers' id='mastersDegreeUpgMoneyCostDisp'> 10,000 </span> dollars
        <br /> </span>
    <span class='tooltipScienceColor'>
        <span class='boldedNumbers' id='mastersDegreeUpgScienceCostDisp'> 100 </span> science
        <br /> </span>
    <span class='tooltipPopularityColor'>
        <span class='boldedNumbers' id='mastersDegreeUpgPopularityCostDisp'> 20 </span> popularity
        <br /> </span>
    <span>----------------------------------------------------------------</span>
    <div>Grad Student Counting: +100%</div>
    <div>Grad Student Science Production: 0.004/sec</div>
</div>
```

I also have upgrade objects, stored in an array. Here's an example of one:

```
name: "Masters Degree",
desc: "Get your grads up to speed.",
moneyCost: 10000,
scienceCost: 100,
popularityCost: 20,
requirement: (resources.science.amount >= 70),
buildingAffected: BUILDINGS[1],
buildingCurrencyAffected: null,
upgVal: 3,
upgProdResource: null,
upgProdAmount: null,
id: 'mastersDegreeUpg',
index: 2
```

The main goal I want to accomplish is to:
1) When an upgrade fulfills a requirement, it is added to the table. However, the issue I run into when I try to do something like:

```
var table = getId('upgradeTable');    
table.appendChild(tr = document.createElement("tr"));
tr.appendChild(td = document.createElement("td"));
td.innerHTML = // ????? 
td.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

What would go in the `td.innerHTML`? Is it even possible to add that amount of HTML with js?

I tried making a property `HTML` of the upgrade object that had the HTML listed, then using `td.innerHTML = //(upgrade object goes here).html` but I got an error that `JSX expressions must have at least one parent` (I'm only a few weeks into coding so I have no idea what that means).

The main REASON why I want to do this (in case there's a better and alternate method) is so that my table of upgrades (which has one column and as many rows as there are visible upgrades) will automatically condense empty space. When I had fixed table elements (already placed into the HTML, and all that changed was visibility), if the player didn't unlock the upgrades sequentially (which is impossible given my current design), there would be a lot of white space between the upgrade before it and that upgrade (if one unlocked upgrade was in row index 2 and the next was in row index 6, there would be three blank white spots in between). Since I want over 200 upgrades in this game (with at least 15-20 displayed at one time) it's necessary for me to condense them to avoid running out of page room.

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't implicitly create global variables, and don't assign inside of conditional statements if at all possible - declare the variables beforehand instead, if you have to.

But yes, it's possible (and pretty easy) to append that much HTML at once, using template literals:

```
const table = getId('upgradeTable');    
const tr = document.createElement("tr")
table.appendChild(tr);
const td = document.createElement("td")
tr.appendChild(td);
td.innerHTML = `
<button id="mastersDegreeUpgButton"class="upgradeButtons"onClick="upgrade(UPGRADES[returnIndex(UPGRADES,'mastersDegreeUpg')])">Masters Degree </button>     
<div class='tooltip' id='mastersDegreeUpgTooltip'> 
<span>Get your grad students into shape! And off a diet of ramen. <br /> </span>
<span class='tooltipMoneyColor'> <span class='boldedNumbers' id='mastersDegreeUpgMoneyCostDisp'> 10,000 </span> dollars<br /> </span>
<span class='tooltipScienceColor'> <span class='boldedNumbers' id='mastersDegreeUpgScienceCostDisp'> 100 </span> science<br /> </span>
<span class='tooltipPopularityColor'> <span class='boldedNumbers' id='mastersDegreeUpgPopularityCostDisp'> 20 </span> popularity<br /> </span>
<span>----------------------------------------------------------------</span>
<div>Grad Student Counting: +100%</div>
<div>Grad Student Science Production: 0.004/sec</div>
</div>
`;
td.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

But do note that inline event handlers are essentially `eval` inside HTML markup - they're bad practice and result in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

You might do it like this:

```
const table = getId('upgradeTable');    
const tr = document.createElement("tr")
table.appendChild(tr);
const td = document.createElement("td")
tr.appendChild(td);
td.innerHTML = `
<button id="mastersDegreeUpgButton"class="upgradeButtons">Masters Degree </button>     
<div class='tooltip' id='mastersDegreeUpgTooltip'> 
// ...
`;
// this references the button:
td.children[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
  upgrade(UPGRADES[returnIndex(UPGRADES,'mastersDegreeUpg')]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  Quick question, if I add `td.children[0]` do I need to change the array index based on what upgrade I want or will it always be zero?

Comment: That references the first child of the `td`. Since the line above just assigned to the `td`, and the first element in the HTML string there is the button, `td.children[0]` will always reference the button there.

Comment: Thank you so much!