# Boolean in my object always returning false

Tags: javascript, html

[Followup to another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621645/adding-preformatted-buttons-to-a-table-with-js-to-condense-white-space)

Currently I have this object, which is an upgrade object.

```
{
    name: "Telling a Friend",
    desc: "It all has to start somewhere... \n Money moneyCost ratio reduction: -0.1% \n Popularity: 0.003/sec",
    moneyCost: 30000,
    scienceCost: null,
    popularityCost: null,
    requirement: (resources.science.amount >= 40),
    buildingAffected: player.moneyRatio,
    buildingCurrencyAffected: null,/* The 'building' is just a variable that controls price ratio reduction. */
    upgVal: 0.999,
    upgProdResource: 'popularity',
    upgProdAmount: (0.003/7),
    id: 'tellingAFriendUpg', //Id used to fetch stuff
    html: `<button id="tellingAFriendUpgButton" class="upgradeButtons">Telling A Friend </button>     
    <div class='tooltip' id='tellingAFriendUpgTooltip'> 
        <span>You have to get the word out somehow! Bore your friend with your (currently) useless number. <br /> </span>
        <span class='tooltipMoneyColor'> <span class='boldedNumbers' id='tellingAFriendUpgMoneyCostDisp'> 30,000 </span> dollars<br /> </span>
        <span>----------------------------------------------------------------</span>
            <div>Money Cost Ratio: -0.1% (multiplicative)</div>
            <div class ='tooltipPopularityColor'>Popularity: 0.003/sec</div>
    </div>` ,
    index: 1 //Index to determine what is deleted when you buy the upgrade. Based ONLY upon what order the table is sorted by.
 },
```

What I'm focusing on is this line: `requirement: (resources.science.amount >= 40),`

This boolean ALWAYS returns false and I'm not sure why. I'm trying to pass it through this function:

```
function checkVisiblityOnUpgrades() {
for (let iter of UPGRADES) {
    var currentUpgrade = iter;
   console.log(iter);
    if (iter.requirement && UPGRADESPURCHASED.includes(iter.id) == false) {
    console.log('hello')
        /* Null Checks before updating html */
        var table = getId('upgradeTable');    
        table.appendChild(tr = document.createElement("tr"));
        tr.appendChild(td = document.createElement("td"));
        td.innerHTML = iter.html;
        console.log(td.innerHTML);
        console.log(td);
// this references the button:
        td.children[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
        upgrade(UPGRADES[returnIndex(UPGRADES,iter.id)]);
        });
        if ((getId(currentUpgrade.id.concat("ScienceCostDisp")) != null))
            getId(currentUpgrade.id.concat("ScienceCostDisp")).innerHTML = currentUpgrade["scienceCost"];
        if (getId(currentUpgrade.id.concat("MoneyCostDisp")) != null)
            getId(currentUpgrade.id.concat("MoneyCostDisp")).innerHTML = currentUpgrade["moneyCost"];
        if (getId(currentUpgrade.id.concat("PopularityCostDisp")) != null)
            getId(currentUpgrade.id.concat("PopularityCostDisp")).innerHTML = currentUpgrade["popularityCost"];

        }
    }

}
```

However, when I try to `console.log` the object that `iter` is currently using, the requirement section always returns "false," even when I clearly have enough of the resource.

Background info that might help:

- You start with 0 of every currency.
- The visibility function will fire every 5 seconds.
- If the function works as intended, a button will be appended onto an empty table, which has an eventListener that will upgrade the item (with another function) when clicked.

EDIT: Here is my `resources` object:

```
var resources = { //Handles resources of all kinds.
number: 1000000000,
money: {
    amount: 0, // Raw amount, unrounded until numFormat().
    upgProd: 0 //Amount gained from upgrades per TICK.
    },
science: {
    amount: 0,
    upgProd: 0
    },
popularity: {
    amount: 0,
    upgProd: 0 //Amount produced from upgrades.
    }
};
```

[Picture of my currencies at the time](https://gyazo.com/2cc1e9daaa7d97184846b92a8b3c2f9c)

[Picture of my object that is printed in the console](https://gyazo.com/50eeb407c647279a3684ad86949db9c0)

Thank you!

Comment: What is `resources.science.amount`

Comment: Will post it @brk

Comment: Sorry to state the obvious, but `0 < 40`, so `resources.science.amount >= 40` is falsey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `requirement` property gets set to `true` or `false` immediately on the object's declaration - after it's been evaluated the first time, it doesn't change itself spontaneously. You want a function that you can call that *returns* a boolean, instead of a static boolean value:

```
requirement: () => resources.science.amount >= 40,
```

and then call it with

```
if (iter.requirement() && // ...
```

Comment: so @xufox like `get requirement() { return resources.science.amount >= 40}`?

Comment: @Xufox True, but explicitly calling a function is generally better than what *looks on the outside* to be checking a static property. Using getters when they're not necessary leads to less readable code.